# Please Help: Our Drupal based website is down, seems to be path error mod_rewrite

Tags: drupal, mod-rewrite

Apologies for asking what is likely be a configuration related question, but I've been asked to fix this and have exactly Math.Sqrt(Jack_all) idea on how to fix it.

I can see on the main page that links to the CSS are correctly being requested as

http://www.digitalsignageexperts.co.uk/modules/system/system-menus.css?O

but when we look at a case study, linked from the main page the CSS requests are

http://www.digitalsignageexperts.co.uk/**node**/modules/system/system-menus.css?O

The path /node/ is creeping in from somewhere!

(In this instance the case study uri was http://www.digitalsignageexperts.co.uk/node/51)

Any helpful advice would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: How are your stylesheets added in to the site?

Comment: On first sight, all links (except on the front page) seem to get the leading 'node/', not only those for stylesheets. My first guess would be an erroneous '$base_url' configuration. Check your settings.php file (usually in 'sites/default') for a line setting the $base_url variable ...

Comment: Also, per default, the $base_url variable is not set explicitely, but gets populated automatically from context - so if it is not explicitely set in settings.php, the question would be what got changed on the system lately that could trigger an evaluation to 'node/'?

Comment: $base_url looks to be set correctly in settings.php. This is on a shared host, so I don't know what could have changed - I wondered if they updated php or apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your .htaccess file. Better putting a fresh .htaccess file downloaded from drupal.org.
If nothing changed, try uncommenting `RewriteBase /` in .htaccess file.
I'm not suggesting $base_url because you said it didn't work in comments above.

Comment: How should the RewriteBase (or any mod_rewrite behavior) change the links created by Drupal? (mod_rewrite only operates on incoming requests, not on links created by PHP.)

Comment: Yes, requests. The user says "but when we look at a case study, linked from the main page the CSS requests are" so I thought he's getting 404 reports or something about mis-requested CSS files.

Comment: You're right, in the end, the URLs end up as requests, so concerning that, it could be a messed up rewriting. But from a Drupal perspective, the URLs are 'wrong' in the first place (should not start with 'node/'), so the error seems to originate from the Drupal/PHP side of things. (Unless the URLs have been 'wrong' all the time, and the 'error' had been fixed/kludged by a now defunct rewriting setup - but that seems unlikely.)